# iPhone wipe out

Tags: ios, iphone, disk-format

I have lost and found my iPhone 3Gs. But apparently someone tried to use mine or had some intent to exploit it, and now I am a little paranoid about my iPhone.

Fortunately, I have a very recent backup stored on my laptop and the iOS is up-to-date. I have looked up some references to wipe out the iOS and did factory setting recovery under DFU mode with an ipsw file stored in iTunes. Is this a true complete wipe out of iOS?

(I want basically jail-break and sudo rm -rf / style wipe out. I don't want any funky business such as malware or virus going on my iPhone...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DFU is the lowest-level erasure that you can perform through iTunes. It will eradicate anything that may have been planted on your phone when it was lost. I'd feel safe if I went through the same process.

Answer (score 1):

Take it to an Apple Store.  They will gladly perform a DFU restore, they can also open the phone to inspect and see if there has been some physical tampering.